Cohomology Functor - Homotopic Morphisms Map to the Same Morphism?
For the sake of avoiding confusion, I provide the definition from Achar for this functor: Given an abelian category $\mathbf{A}$ with chain complex $A=((A_j),d_A^{j})$, then the cohomology functor defined such that $H^n(A)=\ker(d_A^n)\ /\ \text{im}(d_A^{n-1})$ (with $H^n(f\in\text{Hom}_{Ch(\mathbf{A})}(A,B))$ defined naturally).
The intended use of this functor is to construct the Derived Category $D(\mathbf{A})$ from the homotopy category $K(\mathbf{A})$. However, in order for functor $H^n$ to be a well-defined functor which satisfies the universal condition with respect to the pairing $(K(\mathbf{A}),H^n)$, Verdier localization -- the localization technique which will be used in constructing $D(\mathbf{A})$ -- requires that we have an additive functor (according to Achar, pg. 485...but I'm getting mixed results on the internet).
(i) Is this functor in fact additive? If so, how do we show this? (ii) If the functor is additive, then it seems straight-forward how homotopic chain maps will map via $H^n$ to the same morphism. However, in the event that $H^n$ is in fact not additive, how do we show this necessary fact?
Thanks all for your time. I really do appreciate any help I can get!

Are you asking whether (co)homology is additive? Yes.

@Trebor Perfect! That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!
